# How can I get the path of a document in opencmis java

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

In my project I query my alfresco repository to get all the documents who have "aspect A" and print all their names, what I want is to get the path of the found documents?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from a [CMIS Document object](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Document.html), you can call [getPaths()](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/FileableCmisObject.html#getPaths%28%29). Assuming the object has a path (with in Alfresco everything other than the root should), it'll be the first one in the list

Your code would be something like:

```
String queryString = "SELECT ......"
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query(queryString, false);

for (QueryResult qResult : results) {
   String objectId = qResult.getPropertyValueByQueryName(objectIdQueryName);
   Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId(objectId));
   List<String> paths = doc.getPaths();
   if (! paths.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(objectId + " lives at " + paths.get(0));
   }
 }
```

Do note that objects can have multiple paths if they're multiply filed